# How to get exact year difference between two dates in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a date of birth column to which I need to compare the current date and return the difference as age. Currently I am using the following query :

```
DECLARE @DateOfBirth date = '2000-07-27'
DECLARE @CurrentDate date = '2015-07-25'

SELECT 
    @Age = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @DateOfBirth, @CurrentDate)
```

I am getting a difference as 15, but the desired result should be 14. This is because it compares the year and gets the difference between 2015 and 2000. So I used the following query :

```
select 
    @Age = CAST(datediff(day, @DOB, @CurrentDate) / 365.2425 AS INT)
RESULT : 14
```

But when I change the Date Of Birth value to '2000-07-25', I still get the value of 14, but it should be 15 since the date difference is exactly 15 years.

How can I get the exact year difference from this?

Comment: There's quite many examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate -- which is the first link I get if I google "age SQL Server"

Comment: But most of the answers to that question are rubbish and get thrown by leap years. The YYYYMMDD method works every time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Subtract one from each other in YYYYMMDD format, and divide by 10000 using integer division (which rounds down).

So:

```
(YEAR(@CurrentDate) * 10000 + MONTH(@CurrentDate) * 100 + DAY(@CurrentDate)
- YEAR(@DateOfBirth) * 10000 - MONTH(@DateOfBirth) * 100 - DAY(@DateOfBirth)
) / 10000
```

20150725-20000727 = 149998, and 149998 / 10000 = 14

You can also use `CONVERT(int,CONVERT(char(8),@CurrentDate,112))`, because style 112 is YYYYMMDD, but that's a little obfuscated in my opinion.

Comment: I agree the 112 style conversion method isn't as intuitive but here's the code for completeness: `(CAST(CONVERT(char(8), @CurrentDate, 112) AS int) - CAST(CONVERT(char(8), @DateOfBirth, 112) AS int)) / 10000`

Answer (score 0):

I have taken Robs method, and turned it into a function, and written a test script for it.
I can no longer find any mistakes.

```
CREATE or alter FUNCTION dbo.CalcAge
(
@DOB date,  /* birthday */
@Today date /* either today or the day you want to calculate the age for */
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    (
    -- from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108078/how-to-get-exact-year-difference-between-two-dates-in-sql-server/108079#108079
    select (YEAR(@Today) * 10000 + MONTH(@Today) * 100 + DAY(@Today)
    - YEAR(@DOB) * 10000 - MONTH(@DOB) * 100 - DAY(@DOB)
    ) / 10000 as Age
)
go


drop table if exists #h
create table #h (dob date, now date, years int, months int, days int)

--     dob        now      years  months  days 
insert into #h
values 
  ('2012-02-29', '2013-02-28',  0, 11, 30)
, ('2012-02-29', '2013-03-01',  1,  0,  0)
, ('2012-02-29', '2016-02-28',  3, 11, 30) 
, ('2012-02-29', '2016-02-29',  4,  0,  0) 
, ('2012-02-29', '2016-03-31',  4,  1,  2)
, ('2012-01-30', '2016-02-29',  4,  0, 30)
, ('2012-01-30', '2016-03-01',  4,  1,  2)
, ('2011-12-30', '2016-02-29',  4,  1, 30)
, ('1822-11-04', '2022-11-04',200,  0,  0)
, ('2000-02-29', '2004-02-28',  3, 11, 30)
, ('1900-02-28', '2000-02-29',100,  0,  0)
, ('1900-02-28', '2001-02-28',101,  0,  0)
, ('2000-02-28', '2104-02-28',104,  0,  0)
, ('2000-02-29', '2104-02-29',104,  0,  0)
, ('2012-03-28', '2017-03-28',  5,  0,  0)
, ('2012-03-28', '2017-03-29',  5,  0,  0)

select *
from #h h
cross apply dbo.CalcAge (dob, now) as A
--where h.years <> a.Age
order by h.dob, h.now
go
drop function if exists dbo.CalcAge
```

Comment: Yes, I've been looking left,right and center to find a solution that is fast and work correctly. The list of dates to test is build on what I've found on the way.
This solution worked the first time.